# ¿Como obtener los valores de los items seleccionados de un CheckBoxList en vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

El problema que tengo es que por más que selecciono un checkbox nunca me lo muestra seleccionado en el depurador de Visual Studio, puedo obtener todos los valores de los items pero solo necesito los seleccionados.

No quiero usar JavaScript.

**Codigo VB**

```vb
For i As Integer = 0 To Roles.Items.Count - 1
    If Roles.Items(i).Selected Then
        MiCargo.pAgregarRolCargo(Roles.Items(i).Value)
    End If
Next
```

¿Me podrían ayudar? No sé qué es lo que sucede.

Comment: ¿es una aplicación de asp.net? puedes poner tu código HTML o asp?

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que tienes que hacer es determinar que check lo tienes activo, y luego recorrer para que captures los valores.

```vb
If CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count <> 0 Then
    For i As Integer = 0 To Roles.Items.Count - 1
        If Roles.Items(i).Selected Then
            MiCargo.pAgregarRolCargo(Roles.Items(i).Value)
        End If
    Next
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

Ejemplo sencillo de recorrer el listview:

```
Private Sub BtnAgregar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnAgregar.Click
        Dim qry As String = ""
        Dim qactualizo As String = ""
        Dim x1 As Date = DateTimePicker3.Value

        Dim fechapago As String
        fechapago = Format(x1, "MM/dd/yyyy")

        For Each item As ListViewItem In LvLista.CheckedItems

            qactualizo = ""
            qactualizo += "  Pagada = True"
            qactualizo += ", Fecha_Pago = '" & fechapago & "'"
            qactualizo += ", Bimestre = '" & CboPeriodo.Text & "'"
            qactualizo += ", Ano = '" & CboAno.Text & "'"

            qry = String.Format("Update facturas set " & qactualizo & " where Id_Factura = " & item.SubItems(0).Text & "")
            EjecutaCmd(qry)
            item.Remove()
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: es una forma sencilla de recorrer el listview